# Django - ModelForm to template not submitting data

Tags: python, django

my django template is not submitting data! i know it is very basic thing but there is something i cannot realize here! my Model is:

```
class project(models.Model):
    Project_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And my ModelForm is:

```
class create_project(forms.ModelForm):     
  class Meta:
     model = project
     fields = ['Project_Name']
```

views.py

```
def project_create_view(request):
    form = create_project(request.POST or None)
    msg  = ''
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        msg = 'Data Submitted'
        form = create_project()
    return render(request, 'create_project.html', {'form':form, 'msg':msg})
```

And my template is:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <label for="id_Project_Name">Project Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Project_Name" id="id_Project_Name">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>
```

My context dict is 'form', i tried so many ways searched online but no luck, can anyone help?...
I haven't pasted all the project as the case is similar for the rest fields.

Comment: Your example code is incomplete.  Please see how to write a [Minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So what is happening/not that you don't expect? You have also missed out the view function code, which I suspect is where the error really lies. (Without this we have no idea what the `form` context variable contains.)

Comment: sorry for that, i have completed the code. @AlanHoover

Comment: fixed, expecting your help please. @RobinZigmond

Comment: thanks - although you still haven't explained what the problem is. And I see no use of the `form` or `msg` context vars in the template?

Comment: my problem is when i submit data it doesn't get saved in the DB, you see no use of context vars because i did several changes trying to make it work, i don't want to make it long, it would be so appreciated if you can code the template for me in the right way, thanks again.@RobinZigmond

Comment: @MohRaad I'd love to help, but although I know Django I'm no expert, hopefully someone else will be able to fix your problem. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code - and I assume there are no errors thrown? Have you tried printing the value of `form` at the top of the function?

Comment: Even a Django expert can't answer this question, I'm afraid, as there simply isn't a question here. Where are you trying to use this context? What happened when you tried?

Comment: what i want here is to map the the template <input> with my ModelForm, and my problem is i get no data submitted to the DB when i hit the submit button.@DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to solve it this way after taking support from one of my experienced friends:

```
<td>
        <div>
            <label for="{{form.Project_Name.name}}">Project Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Project_Name" id="{{form.Project_Name.name}}">
        </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html,

```
<form method="POST" action="#keep it blank or add action as per your requirement" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <span> {{field.errors}} </span>
    <div> {{field}} </div> #you can add label or placeholder as per your requirement
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

You have not added enctype in your html.
Note : You can modify your views.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i know it work this way as i tried it before but what i wanted is to use the html <input> because i need the datepicker of html5 when using <input type="date">.